# Is there a way to get powershell's autocompletion working for an application?

Tags: .net, powershell

Powershell has great autocomplete, allowing it to easily autocomplete parameters. Is it possible to provide this autocompletion when calling an application? E.g.

```
.\myscript.ps1 -Databa (pressing tab here will fill in Database)
```

but if you eventually decide to replace the script with a proper application

```
.\myapp.exe -Databa (pressing tab does nothing)
```

The application is a .NET application (if that helps). Is there any way for it to hook into whatever powershell is doing to determine the parameters?

Comment: In PowerShell v5 you can use: `Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName myapp.exe -ScriptBlock {some magic here}`. Also I can recommend to replace script by cmdlet, not by application, that should give you more options to integrate with PowerShell, like be able to output objects instead of just text.

Comment: cmdlets are nice but at some point it's just much easier to develop in a full fledged programming language. Most of the time I start out writing quick powershell scripts, and they start to become unmanageable, even if they were cmdlets, and need to be promoted

Comment: Cmdlets can be written in C#. Do you think that C# is not a full fledged programming language? And which full fledged programming language do you use for your .NET application? PowerShell also advertise ability to write cmdlets in not managed languages by implementing CIM providers and export them as CIM cmdlets, but I does not really dig in that field.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize cmdlets could be written in C#. that's probably the route I'll take then

Answer (score 2):

Sort of, yeah. But it's all within powershell; you wouldn't do anything within the .Net executable.

As @PetSerAl pointed out, PowerShell 5 has a much easier way to do it.

But it's still possible in earlier versions (though not well documented) by using a tab completer function.

[posh-git makes use of this to autocomplete git parameters](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/blob/master/GitTabExpansion.ps1).

You might also want to look at [TabExpansionPlusPlus](https://github.com/lzybkr/TabExpansionPlusPlus).